# View Firebird Tables within SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, firebird2.1

I am trying to connect to a Firebird database within SQL Server 2008 R2 and haven't really found a good way to do this?  I'm looking for options on how to connect to a Firebird database...is a linked server an option?...or recommended?

Some details...

SQL Server 2008 R2 machine = 64bit
Firebird machine = 32bit

Firebird client files and ODBC are installed on SQL Server machine and the ODBC tests successfully.

If I expand out the Linked Servers portion in SQL Server, I don't see any providers that look like they would work with Firebird (ADsDSOObject,MSDAOSP,MSDASQL,MSIDXS,MSOLAP,SQLNCLI10,SQLOLEDB).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you add a linked server, you can select "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers" (or MSDASQL) (NOTE: I haven't actually tried this, so that is why I am posting it as a comment).

Comment: I've gotten that far :) I figured this was the provider to use...however I'm not exactly sure what values to put into the provider details

Comment: Looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479%28v=sql.110%29.aspx either the name of the system dsn in _Data Source_ or an ODBC connection string in _Provider string_ should work, other fields should be empty.